# How to change rows in pandas based on an attribute of the other rows

Tags: pandas, sorting, rows

I have a dataframe with columns: A(continuous variable) and B(discrete 1 or 0). The df is initially sorted by A variable.
I need to order the dataframe so for each set of X rows, there are Y rows with value 1 in B column, and (X-Y) rows with 0 (B column) (when possible!). But these sets should have variable A in desceding order. X and Y are input by the user

Example:
X=4, Y=3

[image]

Rows 0-11 are ok, since the sets (0-3),(4-7) and (8-11) has 3 rows with 1 in column B and only one row with 0 AND variable A is descending. However, rows 12-15 are not ok, since there are 2 rows with 1(variable B) and two with 0. Row 17 would replace row 15 to make this set valid. There is no problem if the last rows has 0 in variable B, since there isn't any with value 1.

The code should be general enough to run on dataframes with different number of rows.

Any ideas?